# Undefined append after an ajax post in rubyonrails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to append some information after posting with ajax

this is are my routes:

```
match 'api/people/', to: 'people#people_get_all', via: [:get]
match 'api/people/:id', to: 'people#people_get', via: [:get]

match 'api/people/', to: 'people#create', via: [:post]
```

this is my javascript:

```
var $people = $('#people');
var $first_name = $('#first_name');

$('#add_user').on('click', function(){

    var person = {
        person: {
            first_name: $first_name.val(),
            last_name: $last_name.val(),
            location: $location.val(),
            phone: $phone.val()
        }
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/people/',
        data: person,
        success: function(newPerson){
            $people.append('<p><strong>First Name: </strong>' + newPerson.first_name + '</p>');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('error saving person to database');
        }
    });

});
```

When I click on the button, it will save the record successfully in the database but when the append happens it brings an undefined value.

Do I have something wrong here?

This is the controller:

```
before_action :set_person, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
def create
  @person = Person.new(person_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @person.save
      format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @person }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private

  def set_person
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
  end


  def person_params
    params.require(:person).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :location, :phone)
  end
```

this is what happens after pressing the button, it brings `undefined`

[image]

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Is all the Javascript code inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: hey @Barmar I added a picture on what happens, and no, but I'm guessing I don't need that since it's posting correctly to the database, the problem here is appending the new information added via the post. I have the code under `$(function(){ ... });`

Comment: I thought you were getting a Javascript error saying that `$people.append` is undefined.

Comment: FYI, `$(function...)` is the same as `$(document).ready(function...)`

Comment: You can't render both HTML and JSON in the same call. The HTML will make parsing the JSON fail.

Comment: You also need `dataType: 'json'` in the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: What in `console.log(newPerson)`?

Comment: ah, thank you all, I added `dataType: 'json'` to the ajax call and it worked like a charm. @Barmar make an answer with that so I can upvote you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell `$.ajax` that the response is JSON, using the `dataType:` option.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/people/',
    data: person,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(newPerson){
        $people.append('<p><strong>First Name: </strong>' + newPerson.first_name + '</p>');
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('error saving person to database');
    }
});
```